# Recover orphaned diskspace from ESXi datastore

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, datastore

I was uploading a big file (iso of +/- 6 Gb) and somewhere in the middle I've got an I/O error.
Now I can't see the file in the datastore and I lost +/- 3 Gb.

How can I delete the 'partial' file or reclaim the space?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the way you view the datastore you may or may not be able to see the file. I've noted that the ESX VI client's datastore viewer does not show some files. If you were to ssh into the system and cd to the VM folder on the datastore (**cd /vmfs/volumes/datastore_name/vm_name/**) then you should be able to see the file, it may have a .part extension. (**ls -la** shows all files)

To enable sshd on ESXi see this article:
http://www.yellow-bricks.com/2008/08/10/howto-esxi-and-ssh/

Comment: alas, thank you very much for the tip, but I couldn't find the files or a part of it (*.part)... I think I really lost the gigs now...

Comment: I'm sure the file is still there, it's just hiding out.
Try  using "du -h" from the root of the datastore to see your space utilization, where the 3GB file is hiding might become visible from there. You could also try a "find . -size +2048000" which will list every file over 2GB in size in the current datastore.